# Rails Kaminari - How to Show Pagination Links at the Top and Bottom of the Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

The title pretty much says it all.  I don't want the user to have to scroll back to the top before they can select the next page.

I can pull out the query string and write my own logic to build the appropriate links, but I can't believe this isn't built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, this is the quickest way I've seen to do it.

Kaminari creates this already at the top of the page:

```
<nav class="pagination">
```

So I added, at the bottom of the page:

```
<span class="bottomPageLinks"></span>
```

Then added the following javascript to the page:

```
$(function(){
    $('.pagination').clone().appendTo('.bottomPageLinks');
});
```

If someone knows a native Kaminari route that avoids the added complication, I'd still like to know about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= paginate @your_model %>
```

Should go at the bottom, outside of your ul/form.